# regex find string, parse next string to add character in beginning and end of

Tags: regex, debian

I have to change a couple of thousand lines of code. Looking for a quick way ;)

```
Code in PHP $lang[_SAVE] to be altered to $lang['_SAVE']
```

I need to find [_ and replace it with ['_ and then replace next ] with ']

regex from cmd line in debian would be prefered ;)

EDIT: I need to replace whats between `$lang[_` and `]` with  `'<string between $lang[_ and ]>'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with:

```
<?php
$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(".");

// Loop through files
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file) {
  if ($file->getExtension() == 'php') {
    $content=file_get_contents($file);
    $found = preg_replace('/(?<=lang\[)(_.*?)(?=])/', "'$1'", $content);
    file_put_contents($file, $found);
  }
}
?>
```

with a bit of help of https://www.phpliveregex.com/#tab-preg-replace

It traverse the files recursively and looks for whats between `lang[_` and next `]` and replaces that value with `'<found value>'`